# page redirect in php

Tags: php

I have created one login form and it is redirecting to validatelogin.php and validation happened.

```
      <tr>
        <td>Username / Email</td>
        <td><input name="usr_email" type="text" class="required" id="txtbox" size="25"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input name="pwd" type="password" class="required password" id="txtbox" size="25"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <div align="center">

                <input name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin3" class="styled-button-1" value="Login" />
```

myvalidate.php is :

```
if(empty($err)){

          header("Location: index.php?Page=defaultblog");
}
else
{
  $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";
}
} else {
        $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
}
}
```

In local machine , if no error it redirect to `header("Location: index.php?Page=defaultblog");` but when i upload it inot server it only redirect to `validate.php`
Please tell me?

Comment: I think syntax error in your code because you have write extra curly braces in condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the top of the php code somewhere as I don't think your redirect is being called.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

The key issue will probably be having a space or blank line somewhere before this code which prevents the redirect firing. Once resolved, reset the error reporting if required.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(empty($err)){

       echo '<meta http=equiv="refresh" content="1;url=index.php?Page=defaultblog">';
     }

    else
    {

    $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";

    }
} else {
    $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
  }
```